# How to set specific position for DDPageControl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using `DDPageControl` in my project, but I am unable to place `DDPageControl` to specific position in `UIView`, I have tried to initialize it with the `initWithFrame` method but still it is not showing up as in expected location in my main `UIView`, So how to set it in any specified position. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[pageControl setCenter: CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.bounds.size.height-30.0f)] ;
```

Comment: Can you explain in details please ? i am new !

Comment: set center method is use to set the postion of the pagecontrol in the view. So just set the x point and y point.

Comment: OK Thanks Gaurav Parmar